# Multiple values in single input field using php.

Tags: php, wordpress, input, message

I am doing a project in `php (wordpress)` website. I am stuck in one place and have no idea from where to start.
I am trying to make message system in my project. where admin can send message to the user's. let's say  one user, multiple user, or all the users.

I have one input box where admin can write multiple `emp_no` like, 
`emp1`, `emp1`, `emp3` 
and when admin click on send button message should send to these three employees.

I have no clue from where to start. Please Help.

Comment: For start check [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can the jquery [multiple value input autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple)

and can separate the values using the PHP **explode** function.

Answer (score 4):

Either you can use simple text field such as

```
<input type="text" name="names" id="names">
```

on your back end you can split the string named "names" with coma by simple split methods.

Or if you want to add names with auto dropdown then
You can use JQuery UI auto complete(multiple values)
complete code is available at official Jquery ui documents.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple.